# Creating a web extension that changes a value on a certain webpage with manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, dom-manipulation

I want to make an extension that will help me with my current work, but I've been having trouble making it work. To simplify - I will post the code for an example of an extension that should change the value of the "I'm feeling lucky" button on google.com page to a custom value that the user enters in the popup of the extension.

The issue is that I just can't access the value of the button, no matter how many different methods I've tried.

The extension consists of 4 files: popup.html, popup.js, manifest.json and background.js

manifest.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Lucky Button Changer",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "A Chrome extension that allows users to change the value of the 'I'm feeling lucky' button on google.com",
    "permissions": ["activeTab"],
    "host_permissions": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Popup.html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Lucky Button Changer</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="luckyValue" placeholder="Enter new value for 'I'm feeling lucky' button">
    <button id="changeButton">Change Value</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Popup.js file looks like this:

```
let luckyButton = document.querySelector(
  "#ow6 > div.FPdoLc.lJ9FBc > center > input.RNmpXc"
);

if (luckyButton) {
  luckyButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
    let input = document.getElementById("luckyInput");
    let inputValue = input.value;
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      func: () => {
        let luckyButton = document.querySelector(
          "#ow6 > div.FPdoLc.lJ9FBc > center > input.RNmpXc"
        );
        luckyButton.value = inputValue;
      },
    });
  });
} else {
  console.log("Could not find lucky button on page.");
}
```

and finally, the background.js file looks like this:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: () => {
      chrome.action.openPopup();
    },
  });
});
```

Inside the popup.js file I put the code in a try - catch block just to see if I will get the element, since that is the main issue i've been having. As a result, I get "Could not find lucky button on page." printed in console since I can't get the value of the button. I've been banging my head at this problem for too long now, so I hope someone with extension experience could help me out and get this example to work so I can apply the logic to my actual project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `background` from manifest.json - the chrome.action.onClicked event won't be fired because you've declared `default_popup` in manifest.json.
2. Remove background.js
3. Remove `luckyButton` and `luckyInput` from popup.js and use `luckyValue` instead.
4. Since the popup is a separate window not related to the web page, its script (popup.js) can't see elements of the web page. Conversely, the function injected via executeScript doesn't run in the popup, it runs in the web page, which is why it sees the elements of the web page, but can't see elements or variables of the popup, i.e. it can't see `inputValue`, so you must use executeScript's `args` parameter to pass the arguments into the injected function.
5. Add `defer` to popup.js script tag in popup.html so it runs when the html is parsed

// popup.html

```html
...
<script src="popup.js" defer></script>
...
```

// popup.js

```js
const lv = document.getElementById('luckyValue');
lv.onclick = async () => {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    args: [lv.value],
    func: (val) => {
      let el = document.querySelector(
        '#ow6 > div.FPdoLc.lJ9FBc > center > input.RNmpXc');
      el.value = val;
    },
  });
};
```

Note that just changing `value` is usually insufficient: you also need to add `el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true}))` or use document.execCommand ([example](/a/57900849)).